# printf is not printing out full 2D array

Tags: arrays, 2d

```
for (i = 0; i < 613; i++)
{   
     for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
     {          
         printf("[%s]\t", postcodes[i][j]);
         printf("\n");
     }
}
```

array is a header consisting of 613 postcodes with a suburb attached.

```
char *postcodes[NUM_POSTCODES][2] = 
{ 
    { "7000", "Glebe" },
    { "7000", "Hobart" },
    { "7000", "Mount Stuart" },
    { "7000", "North Hobart" },
    { "7000", "West Hobart" },
    { "7001", "Hobart" },
    { "7002", "North Hobart" },
    { "7004", "Battery Point" },
    ...
}
```

when the program is run it will start printing at post code 7248 which is about half way through the array. I cant find a reason for why it is doing this. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How many lines was printed by your code?   Is the value of NUM_POSTCODES equals to 613?  Where does post code 7248 exist in the array postcode?

Comment: NUM_POSTCODES = 613
7248 exists at line 334 of the code, where the first postcode 7000 exists at line 20. 
so it's 314th element in the array.
What printed was from element 314 to element 612. roughly half the array. 
HOWEVER, removing printf("\n"); the whole array prints out. 
But i need printf("\n"); so the program prints it out neatly like
    7001 hobart
    7002 Newtown
 vertically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BIG 2D Array not printing out fully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089452/big-2d-array-not-printing-out-fully)